# Preserve dimension while reshaping

Tags: pytorch, reshape

Let's say we have a tensor of size `B x C x W x H` (as common for batches of images), and we want to reshape it to `B x M` where `M = C*W*H`. Is there a built in way to do so without explicitly mentioning `B`?

If we know `B` in advance we can do following, even without explicitly knowing any of the three `C,W,H`:

```
a = torch.randn(20,3,512,512)
b = a.reshape((20, -1)) #we can use -1 to infer the dimension `M`
```

But can we also do so without knowing `B`?

(I know we could obviously find `B` using `B = a.shape[0]`, but my question is whether it is possible without knowing `B` either.)

Comment: Since C,W,H are probably constant while B might vary, maybe `b = a.reshape((-1, C*W*H))` would make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The **only other way** would be to calculate the second dimension and use -1 for the first.

```
a = torch.randn(20,3,512,512)
print(a.shape)
b = a.reshape((20, -1)) 
print(b.shape)
b = a.reshape((-1, 786432)) # 3*512*512
print(b.shape)
```

---

```
torch.Size([20, 3, 512, 512])
torch.Size([20, 786432])
torch.Size([20, 786432])
```

Because there can be only one `-1` when reshape.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you could make it a generic function working with any batch size by simply using first dimension of input, e.g.:

```
a = torch.randn(20, 3, 512, 512)
b = a.reshape((a.shape[0], -1))
```

You can wrap it in a function and just call it whenever necessary.